# How to silently authenticate a multi-tenant Teams bot on behalf of a user?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

How can I authenticate a multi-tenant bot silently on behalf of a user? I'm trying to replicate the behavior of the Microsoft Flow bot in Teams. This bot does not prompt the user to authenticate with an Oauth2 card, and it seamlessly retrieves my flows. How can I get the token of the current session from Teams to use it, for example, in a call to the Graph API?
[image: MS Bot Flow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-silent-aad):

> Currently, silent authentication only works for tabs. It does not yet work when signing in from a bot.

That being said, if you create a bot that has tabs, the user can click on the tab to silently authenticate. It's not ideal, but for now, that's all there is.

[The official Teams Sample Bot](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node) does this.

Follow the linked sample and docs to accomplish this. The docs, especially, lay it out pretty well.

Comment: this answer is currently outdated by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots

Answer (score 2):

Update : SSO is now supported for Tabs, Bots and Messaging Extension.
Please take a look at following documentation:

[Single sign-on (SSO) support for tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso?tabs=dotnet)

[Single sign-on (SSO) support for bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots)

[Single sign-on (SSO) support for messaging extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/enable-sso-auth-me)

Comment: Hi @Wajeed-MSFT. You answer is from back in 2019. Is this still the case?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.  Updated the answer for SSO support.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth prompt can be used to sign in the user. As of now , the user needs to sign  in only once,then when the token expires , the user will be authenticated silently.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv1%2Ccsharp%2Cbot-oauth

Please check out this sample:
 https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication

Comment: i need to authenticate the user silently and regardless about the tenant, like the example in ms team flow's bot. i'm already using that kind of authentication, but i want to make a multi tenant bot. thanks for your answer. this is the link of the bot that i want to copy https://teams.microsoft.com/l/app/c3a1996d-db0f-4857-a6ea-7aabf0266b00