# How to receive user photos in MS Teams Bot which installed in different organizations?

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

According to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-beta - in order to get the user photo we need to perform HTTP request [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userId}/photo/$value](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/%7BuserId%7D/photo/$value) providing the access token and user id.
Using the client credentials flow I can receive the access token for a specifiс organization (tenant id), for example:

```
public static String getAppAccessToken(String[] scopes) {
        ConfidentialClientApplication cca;
        try {
            cca = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(applicationId, ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(applicationSecret))
                    .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<tenantId>>/")
                    .build();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        }

        Set<String> scopeSet = Set.of(scopes);

        ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParam = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(
                scopeSet)
                .build();

        CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = cca.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam);
        return future.join().accessToken();
    }
```

But the access token received in such way allows to receive photos only for users of the organization, which has the same tenant id with the tenant id of the bot app registered in Azure Active Directory App Registration.
Is it possible to receive the photos of the users from other organizations where my bot is installed, using client credentials flow token?
In this case I receive:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"NoPermissionsInAccessToken\",\"message\":\"The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.\",\"innerError\":{\"oAuthEventOperationId\":\"d90f2331-a22a-44d5-889e-c0c14ea9129e\",\"oAuthEventcV\":\"n+NecjM040KWn+2G+e5oFQ.1\",\"errorUrl\":\"https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidGrant\",\"requestId\":\"0b6bb579-94a7-47ac-8ff9-26ee893e5cb0\",\"date\":\"2021-01-28T00:57:52\"}}}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-01-28T00:57:52",
            "request-id": "0b6bb579-94a7-47ac-8ff9-26ee893e5cb0",
            "client-request-id": "0b6bb579-94a7-47ac-8ff9-26ee893e5cb0"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56503643/how-to-connect-to-any-tenant-like-bot-microsoft-flow-in-teams/56754309 is about the same as mine!

Answer (score 1):

I'm certainly no expert on auth, but here are two suggestions to look in to, in case this can help:

1. "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<>/" -> use "organizations" instead of tenant id
2. check what scopes you're using (you don't list what you're trying, so it might be this)

Answer (score 0):

Just try using "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common" endpoint and see if you can get this working. Please read more on that in detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-your-code-to-send-requests-to-common).

You can even send REST request to individual tenant's get the access token and access the information accordingly. Please be aware of having scopes while sending request.

Comment: could you please tell me which REST request I should send to individual tenantId to get the access token and access the information accordingly?

Comment: You need to first retrieve bearer token using [client cred flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) and then use get [Photo API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Using client credential flow (described above in my question) I receive an error for .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<tenantId>>/") and for .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/"). Using client cred flow and .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<tenantId>>/") I can receive User Photo only for user, who is registered in the same tenant (organisation), where the app is registered. May be before receiving a bearer token I need to perform some authentication steps in order the external tenant (client tenant) can trust my App tenant?

Comment: You need to make two separate calls with different tenant id to "login.microsoftonline.com/<<tenantId>>" get access tokens and access them accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried using a [multi tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#multi-tenant-applications-and-caching-access-tokens) application? if still issue persist You need to make two separate calls with different tenant id to "login.microsoftonline.com/<<tenantId>>" get respective access tokens and send request to graph API accordingly.